# Is there a quicker method rather than this to insert all pictures at once

Tags: jquery, html

I have a photo gallery, images are named from 0 to 170 and I am inserting them like so:

```
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- load Galleria -->
        <script src="galleria-1.2.7.min.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Galleria Classic Theme</h1>
        <p>Demonstrating a basic gallery example.</p>

        <!-- Adding gallery images. We use resized thumbnails here for better performance, but it’s not necessary -->

        <div id="galleria">
            <a href="images/0.jpg">
                <img src="images/0.jpg">
            </a>
           <a href="images/1.JPG">
                <img src="images/1.JPG">
            </a>
            <a href="images/2.JPG">
                <img src="images/2.JPG">
            </a>
           <a href="images/3.JPG">
                <img src="images/3.JPG">
            </a>
          <a href="images/4.JPG">
                <img src="images/4.JPG">
            </a>
           <a href="images/5.JPG">
                <img src="images/5.JPG">
            </a>
                  </div>

        <p class="cred">Made by <a href="http://galleria.aino.se">Galleria</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
```

Can I use a method where i do not need to type in the name of each photograph?

Comment: `for` loops usually do things _one at a time_. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what have you tried, and what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing this at the server, not on the client in JavaScript.

However, to answer your question,

```
   var escape_amount = 170, resHtml = '', ii;
   for (ii = 0; ii < escape_amount; ii++)
   {
      resHtml += '<a href="images/'+ii+'.jpg"><img src="images/'+ii+'"></a>';
   }
   $('#galleria').html(resHtml);
```

Comment: 'You should be doing this at the server, not on the client in JavaScript.' Really depends on the architecture of the site. If you're using client side MVC (which is great for UX) then you'll be doing a lot of things like this.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  I am of the school who believes that there are only very few instances where you should be making wholesale modifications to the DOM at the client, at least not without providing  properly semantic markup over the wire.

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike I think that is old school, nowadays many application require wholesale modification of DOM, server only acts like a database

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike I respect your opinion, but I personally believe it's a lot nicer to the user to make an instant change to the DOM as a user takes action and then use AJAX in the background to persist the action via a RESTful API. Makes things seem quicker, even if in reality it takes the same time :)

Comment: @Anurag Uniyal - That's not old school.  Old school is POJ with no semantics, which was a huge contributing factor in the dark ages of JavaScript+CSS (say 1999-2006).  Semantic markup is almost always a better choice, for reasons too numerous to list in this small textbox.

Comment: @djlumley - yeah, that's fine.  Making changes to the DOM is one thing... but to write your pages from the outset like that (which I infer is what is happening here) is just wrong on almost every level.  Might as well be doing document.writeln's.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to dynamically generate such list of images

1. On server side if you can generate HTML dynamically you can do it in whatever server side language/template language you are using
2. On client side you can insert the image nodes dynamically and luckily JavaScript has a for loop

e.g.

```
var galleria = $('#galleria')
for(var i=0;i<170;i++){
    var imgName = "images/"+i+".JPG"
    galleria.append('<a href="'+imgName+'"><img src="'+imgName+'"></a>')
}
```

Benefit on client side is that in some case you can be lazy and don't insert any image until needed or insert whatever quantity needed, hence faster page load time.

Comment: the script is part of a jquery photo gallery. How do I add it to a server?

Comment: @luke what is jquery photo gallery? anyway you are currently writing by hand and serving from server, which instead can be done by some code on server

Comment: @luke yes code there, inside jQuery `onload` function callback

Comment: inside jQuery onload function callback?

Comment: @luke - http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready() It always helps to understand the tools you're using rather than just copying and pasting ^_^